# CSS Style definition appears not to be respected when HTML 5 doctype is used

Tags: css, html

I've started out trying to build a HTML 5 website but have ran into a problem with CSS. Below is a MCVE of the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    div.content {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: left;
        width: 75%;
    }

    div.topbar {
        background-color: #777777;
        border-bottom: 1px #000000 solid;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
<div class="topBar">
<p>MCVE</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
<p>Here is some content.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you take out the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag, the top bar across the top of the page works but if you put it in, it doesn't render correctly as the background colour of the div element is not rendered and neither is the border.

What am I doing wrong here so that the div.topBar style definition isn't being fully respected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that

```
div.topbar
```

Should be

```
div.topBar
```

Because `<div class="topBar">` is not `<div class="topbar">`

It is still being rendered in quirks mode for some reason but html5 mode wont render it.

([Demo](http://jsbin.com/fibafonuni/edit?html,output))

Answer (score 0):

HTML and CSS are case sensitive. 
'topbar' and 'topBar' are different.  Either capitalize the name of the class or correct the `div.topbar`.